# Neo4j Clustering of DB Created using JavaApi and cypher

Tags: neo4j, load-balancing

i use Java API with CYPHER to create database ( node and relation) with help of GraphDatabaseFactory and Executation  Engine.
now got transation error when cluster the db . is it possible ?
i am not using any Neo4j server nor RestAPI.

---

```
i use this step for creating the DB instance 

GraphDatabaseService graphDb =new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()
        .newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder("/home/db/graph")
.loadPropertiesFromFile("neo4j.properties").newGraphDatabase();

neo4j property file  : change for each instance contain following prope

ha.server_id=1
ha.initial_hosts=127.0.0.1:5001,127.0.0.1:5002

i got the error for  but i add the neo4j-server jar 2.0 version M06:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/com/Server$Configuration
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.createIdGeneratorFactory(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:437)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:480)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.create(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:168)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:304)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
    at com.migrate.work.Migrate.sample(Migrate.java:18)
    at com.migrate.work.Migrate.main(Migrate.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.com.Server$Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please add more details on what you already did, as well as the full error message/stacktrace. And your HA config for the cluster you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

What is your use-case for using HA with embedded?

Yes, see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html#editions

You would use this API http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-enterprise/2.0.0/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.html#newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder(java.lang.String)

and pass in your HA config e.g. read from a file (e.g. with http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/helpers/collection/MapUtil.html#load(java.io.File))
or manually.